# How to calculate a percentage in quicksight?

Tags: dax, amazon-quicksight

How to write a formula for calcualted field in quicksight?

```
(countIf({car_unit_id}, {price_in_euro} > 1000000) / count({car_unit_id})) * 100
```

Where would I get a result percentage of all cars that have price greater than 1M?

Answer (score 0):

This solution was simple

```
(countIf({price_in_euro}, {price_in_euro} > 1000000) / count({price_in_euro})) * 100
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?